# Access Django App from subdomain redirect

Tags: django, subdomain

I have a small django app running onn some rootserver. Its using the django integrated dev server. The url is known only to a few people so think thats ok for now. We can access the website by:

```
http://<ip>:<Port>/main
```

A colleague has set up a subdomain like shortcut.somedomain.com that points to the above url.

When trying to access the site via that subdomain the view and template are loaded, but it fails loading the static files. Is there any quick fix to make it work?

Comment: Why don't switch to using a normal web-server and let it serve static? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/.

Comment: I will eventually do this, but I think it will take some time since I have to learn about webserver configuration, wsgi and all this. Hence I was asking for a quick fix until then :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the code that states which are the static files directories and an example where you use a static file in a template?

Is it possible you're loading the static dirs from a wrong path? 
Or maybe you use refer to the files incorrectly in the template?

try doing:

```
my_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
```

this will get you the project root.

after that(make modifications if your project structure is different):
    STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(my_path, 'static')

and this should work with your STATIC_URL definition

Comment: Hello Roman, in my settings.py i specify: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` and in my template I use for example: `{% load staticfiles %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}" />`

Comment: have a look at [django staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)
the first couple of lines talk about production vs. dev environments and how to explicitly add a static dir.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I have to read and gain more knowledge in order to fully understand where exactly the problem is. Usually I 'cheat' by guessing wildly and test example code snippets I found with google, but it aint working this time ...